# What is the relation of $\lambda^\to$ and $\lambda^{\to\times}$ to cartesian closed categories?

Tags: type-theory, category-theory

I am learning about the categorical semantics of type theory. I've written some preliminary results [in Agda](https://github.com/Trebor-Huang/combinator-nbe). In particular, I partially proved that the contexts and substitutions of simply-typed lambda calculus ($\lambda^\to$) forms a cartesian closed category, and I think I can prove that it is the free one over its base types.

But what if I add binary products into the calculus? Since pairs seems to be interpreted by categorical products, this doesn't seem to add anything to the categorical side. My question is: Does the contexts and substitutions in STLC with pairs ($\lambda^{\to\times}$) still form the free CCC over the base types?

My guess is that they do, and the category is equivalent to the category of $\lambda^\to$. Is this correct? Is there any literature discussing this matter?

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://cstheory.stackexchange.com. Do we have the ability to redirect questions there?